# How to fix docker services failing with generic error?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I have an issue in which Gitlab CI jobs are failing with an error like:
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375. Is the docker daemon running?

This doesn't really say much and doesn't make any sense because locally the connection can be established and the commands work as expected.

Commands: build / login / push (are set in the gitlab-ci.yml), but they don't work when using the custom gitlab-runners configured on our server.

Do you have any suggestions for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hello**,

I have had the same problem a couple of days ago with minimum / limited chance of finding the solution.

This is actually a known issue, you can find all of the details here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/4501

Using *docker:latest* in your containers will definitely lead you at some point to this problem.

---

**Short answer** (if this is your case):

Docker *19.03* enables TLS by default, thus the configurations for certificates are required:

1. Add in your **config.toml** (/etc/gitlab-runner/)

`[[runners]]
  environment = ["DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR="]`

2. Add in your **gitlab-ci.yml** (from the project)

`variables:
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""`

---

This will offer the mandatory configurations for finding the certificates  and run properly even though they are not any set (yet, or ever).

It will resolve your problem **for the moment**, hopefully will be fixed in future docker images.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, Rares! This fixed my problem :)

Comment: Worth noting: **Either** Option 1 **or** 2 is sufficient!